# PHP function to check if the string is a properly-formatted English sentence?

Tags: php

Is there any built-in function for that? If not, then how would it look like?

Comment: By 'properly formatted' do you mean it needs to check if the sentence does not contain characters or entities that are not present in English alphabet, or do you want to check if a sentence is a properly constructed (in syntax and morphology and semantics) english sentence, as a native english speaker would tell? You know, this goes far away from the field of programming languages..

Answer (score 2):

You may have a look at the results of [Natural Language Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing), which is a research field of its own.

Unfortunately, there is no built-in PHP function, no ready-to-use algorithm, no 100%-reliable method to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

No. Things like that are also not easily to detect as there are tons of possibilities to make valid sentences.

But you could look for a thesaurus which can be either embedded into php as a library or executed via `stystem()`

Comment: Well, how about the version in which string don't have to be the proper sentence, but at least look like one?